# ¿Por qué onChange no provoca re render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Tengo un *select* para hacer un sort entre "price" y "alph", el *select* cambia, se ejecuta el *callback*. El *callback* `setSort`, cambia el estado el cual esta siendo monitoreado por un *useEffect*, dentro de él se toma el array de productos y los ordena, acto seguido se hace el `setProducts` pongo un `cosole.log` de los productos y efectivamente están ordenados como quiero, pero no se pintan los cambios en la pantalla, sino hasta la segunda vez que hago clic en el select.

El código de ejemplo seria algo así:

```js
function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);
  const [sort,setSort] = useState()
  ...cosas del query

  useEffect(() => {
    api.search(query).then(data => {
      if(sort === 'price'){
        const x = data.sort((a,b) => a.price > b.price ? 1 :-1)
        setProducts(x)
        console.log(products);
        
      }

      if(sort === 'alph'){
        const x = data.sort((a,b) => a.title > b.title ? 1 :-1)
        setProducts(x)
        console.log(products);
      }
       
    });
  }, [sort]);
  

  return (
    <main>
      <select onChange={(e)=>setSort(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="price">Price</option>
        <option value="alph">Alph</option>
        </select>
      <ul>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <li key={product.id}>
            <h4>{product.title}</h4>
            <p>{product.description}</p>
            <span>$ {product.price}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Tenia entendido que cuando en react se hacia un `set` se producia un re render, después.

El problema ya lo resolví, usando un useMemo y ahí si cuando el valor de sort cambia modifica el orden de los product. Pero yo necesito entender porque!!

**Edit:** Si seteo los productos con el spread `setProducts([...x])`, también funciona.

¿Esto pasa porque `x` es el mismo objeto en memoria y no toma como que hubo un cambio? y al hacer el spread es como que estoy pasándole una copia y entonces ¿Al tener otra referencia en memoria lo re renderiza?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288154/react-component-doesnt-rerender-after-sorting-array-in-store

Comment: @AgustinG. Genial es como dije en mi ultimo parrafo entonces, al ocupar el mismo espacio en memoria no produce re-render, y al hacer el spread si que cambia.Si queres ponelo como respuesta y la marco como correcta, sino en estos días lo pondré yo...Gracias!